# How to insert a full width table in a Rmarkdown pdf with two columns?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I am struggling to create a table in a Rmarkdown document with two columns of text. I would like the table to occupy the full with of the page, just like if I use the `\begin{table*}` command in latex.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Me"
output: pdf_document

classoption: twocolumn
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# This is a title

This text is in the left.

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
a=c(1, 2, 3), 
b=c(4, 5, 6), 
c=c(4, 5, 6), 
d=c(4, 5, 6), 
e=c(4, 5, 6)
)

kbl(
  data,
  caption = "This is a table",
  booktabs = TRUE
  ) %>%
  kable_styling(
    latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down")
    )
```
````

I have even tried the `full_width = T`, but doesn't do what I want. I can't find any information about the way to solve it. Anyone can help me, please? Thanks!

I would like to get something like:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What type of error are you seeing?

Comment: What if you do `full_width=T` without `"scale_down"?

Comment: @bttomio I get no error, I just get the full-width table in one of the text columns,s not all page.

Comment: @eipi10, I have tried it, but I keep getting the table in one of the columns.

Comment: Ah, now I see. can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @eipi10 I have reformulated the question. I hope this got clearer now! Thanks.

Comment: You might need to switch back and forth between two-column and one-column layouts to do this. Check the [multicolumn layout](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html) section of the *rmarkdown cookbook*. Toward the bottom it shows how to define a latex preamble for rmarkdown documents that will allow you to switch between 1 and 2 column layouts.

Comment: Thank you @eipi10, I was hoping for something simpler, but that does the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, this code works fine. I just removed the `scale_down` from `latex_options`.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Me"
output: pdf_document

classoption: twocolumn
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# This is a title

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu egestas turpis, et condimentum est. Donec id ultrices lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed ornare, urna vitae pretium pulvinar, tortor leo sodales ligula, nec rhoncus nibh felis vel odio. Cras vulputate justo ac quam varius, vitae feugiat dolor lacinia. Aliquam dictum leo vel tristique volutpat. Vivamus malesuada commodo sapien ut interdum. Duis rhoncus condimentum magna non venenatis.

Phasellus varius, eros at venenatis aliquam, turpis orci pulvinar libero, ut convallis diam lorem vel mauris. Duis nunc diam, vulputate eget nulla ullamcorper, facilisis lacinia neque. Curabitur cursus erat mi, eu imperdiet purus sagittis consequat. Donec tincidunt arcu ipsum, in bibendum velit sagittis eu. In efficitur porttitor pharetra. Nullam feugiat varius neque tempor consequat. Sed sit amet justo vel libero iaculis congue. Pellentesque diam nibh, pretium nec imperdiet in, mattis id dui. Mauris porta dictum tempus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam varius nunc id faucibus egestas. Duis vulputate lacinia est quis pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum pellentesque nisi sed felis volutpat pulvinar. Suspendisse lacinia suscipit libero. Duis eu ex eu sem ultricies dignissim eu id eros.

In lacinia ex eu mi faucibus malesuada et eget purus. In sit amet molestie erat. Nam dui mi, dignissim ut lobortis malesuada, tincidunt id tellus. Duis sed ultricies elit. Mauris a hendrerit velit. Praesent vel feugiat ex, et consequat magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Mauris tempor sagittis purus ac pellentesque. Phasellus mattis erat in elit sodales, at varius massa rutrum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec non maximus tortor. Aliquam porttitor at neque vel tincidunt. Nam et justo mi. Nam lacinia vel dolor et eleifend. Fusce consectetur placerat ultrices. Sed efficitur congue lacus non laoreet. Donec mi enim, tempus ut lectus vitae, congue aliquam massa. Sed eget lectus eu mi tristique aliquam. Praesent sagittis ornare rhoncus. Nunc sapien urna, semper sed sagittis eget, aliquet sed ex. Fusce vitae tellus egestas risus condimentum molestie at sit amet sem. Vivamus ac nunc mauris. Vestibulum id leo euismod, consectetur augue sit amet, maximus libero.

In ut orci feugiat, blandit ligula sed, tincidunt libero. Sed vel nisi sapien. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ullamcorper turpis non mauris mollis auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus accumsan orci sit amet est porta finibus. Vivamus commodo, diam non vulputate finibus, mauris purus commodo erat, pharetra cursus justo neque sit amet erat. Cras ut semper urna. 

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  a=c(1, 2, 3), 
  b=c(4, 5, 6), 
  c=c(4, 5, 6), 
  d=c(4, 5, 6), 
  e=c(4, 5, 6)
)

kbl(data,
  caption = "This is a table",
  booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position"), full_width = T)
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu egestas turpis, et condimentum est. Donec id ultrices lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed ornare, urna vitae pretium pulvinar, tortor leo sodales ligula, nec rhoncus nibh felis vel odio. Cras vulputate justo ac quam varius, vitae feugiat dolor lacinia. Aliquam dictum leo vel tristique volutpat. Vivamus malesuada commodo sapien ut interdum. Duis rhoncus condimentum magna non venenatis.

Phasellus varius, eros at venenatis aliquam, turpis orci pulvinar libero, ut convallis diam lorem vel mauris. Duis nunc diam, vulputate eget nulla ullamcorper, facilisis lacinia neque. Curabitur cursus erat mi, eu imperdiet purus sagittis consequat. Donec tincidunt arcu ipsum, in bibendum velit sagittis eu. In efficitur porttitor pharetra. Nullam feugiat varius neque tempor consequat. Sed sit amet justo vel libero iaculis congue. Pellentesque diam nibh, pretium nec imperdiet in, mattis id dui. Mauris porta dictum tempus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam varius nunc id faucibus egestas. Duis vulputate lacinia est quis pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum pellentesque nisi sed felis volutpat pulvinar. Suspendisse lacinia suscipit libero. Duis eu ex eu sem ultricies dignissim eu id eros.

In lacinia ex eu mi faucibus malesuada et eget purus. In sit amet molestie erat. Nam dui mi, dignissim ut lobortis malesuada, tincidunt id tellus. Duis sed ultricies elit. Mauris a hendrerit velit. Praesent vel feugiat ex, et consequat magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Mauris tempor sagittis purus ac pellentesque. Phasellus mattis erat in elit sodales, at varius massa rutrum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec non maximus tortor. Aliquam porttitor at neque vel tincidunt. Nam et justo mi. Nam lacinia vel dolor et eleifend. Fusce consectetur placerat ultrices. Sed efficitur congue lacus non laoreet. Donec mi enim, tempus ut lectus vitae, congue aliquam massa. Sed eget lectus eu mi tristique aliquam. Praesent sagittis ornare rhoncus. Nunc sapien urna, semper sed sagittis eget, aliquet sed ex. Fusce vitae tellus egestas risus condimentum molestie at sit amet sem. Vivamus ac nunc mauris. Vestibulum id leo euismod, consectetur augue sit amet, maximus libero.

In ut orci feugiat, blandit ligula sed, tincidunt libero. Sed vel nisi sapien. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ullamcorper turpis non mauris mollis auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus accumsan orci sit amet est porta finibus. Vivamus commodo, diam non vulputate finibus, mauris purus commodo erat, pharetra cursus justo neque sit amet erat. Cras ut semper urna.
````

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: The idea was to have a page's full-width table, not one column. Even though, thank you @bttomio.